# LISP Programming Exam Review Q

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

Using the built-in map and zip functions, define a Scheme function zipadd that takes two lists of numbers and returns the a list consisting of the corresponding elements added together. You may assume that the lists are the same length. For example (zipadd '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6)) is (5 7 9). (A correct solution not using zip and map will be worth 8 points.)

I am not sure how to do this. I would really like to know the solution before my exam tomorrow. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, Racket doesn't come with a `zip` procedure, although it's trivial to implement one:

```
(define (zip lst1 lst2)
  (map list lst1 lst2))
```

Now regarding your question - a solution using only `map` is the simplest way to solve this problem and it's *very* similar to the above procedure, just think what could be used to fill the blank:

```
(define (zipadd lst1 lst2)
  (map <???> lst1 lst2))
```

Although it's a bit more contrived, you can use `zip` to reach the same solution (and get full marks). Try to figure out how it works - `zip` sticks together all pairs of elements in both lists, creating a list of two-element lists. Afterwards, `map` will traverse that list and apply a procedure to each element (remember: each element is a list of two elements), creating a new list with the results:

```
(define (zipadd lst1 lst2)
  (map (lambda (x) <???>) ; x is a list with two numbers, how to add them?
       (zip lst1 lst2)))
```

Finally and for completeness' sake, a solution without using `map` or `zip`. It's an implementation of `map` for the special case where the numbers on both lists must be added pair-wise:

```
(define (zipadd lst1 lst2)
  (if <???>                         ; if either list is empty (*)
      <???>                         ; then return the empty list
      (cons (+ <???> <???>)         ; else add the first elements of both lists
            (zipadd <???> <???>)))) ; and advance the recursion over both lists
```

(*) Remember: both lists are assumed to have the same length.

Try to write all the variations of the solution, it'll be interesting to compare different approaches to solve the same problem. And if you *have to* use `map` and `zip` to get full marks then by all means use the second version above, just be aware that's not the simplest nor the most efficient way to express the solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: Ok, I should just be able to use car and cdr to add the list together. But i keep getting an error. Thanks for the help by the way. DO you kno what I am doing wrong?

Comment: (define (zipadd lst1 lst2)
  (map (lambda (x) (+ (car x)(cdr x))) ; x is a list with two numbers, how to add them?
       (zip lst1 lst2)))

Comment: `cdr` is not the way to go. Use `car` to extract the current element of a list and `cdr` to advance to the rest of the list. And actually, it's much simpler than that, you don't even need a `lambda` for the first version - see how it worked for `list` in my definition of `zip`

Comment: Ya but i need to use both zip and map to get the full credit it says, so i want to use both of them.

Comment: http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi-std/srfi-1.html#zip.  Also note that `map` consumes a function, but that function doesn't have to always be a function of one argument.

Comment: @user977154 then use the second version of `zipadd`, and re-read what I said: your answer is mostly correct, except the part where the addition is performed - you're adding a number with a list, and that's an error.